# Check for substring in element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble looking at an H1 tag and then populating an empty div with an image based upon the contents of said H1.  My code is as follows:

```
// DECLARE MEASURMENT STEP IMAGES
var CornerRight = "../product_images/uploaded_images/onecutcornerrightstep2.gif";
var CornerLeft = "../product_images/uploaded_images/onecutcornerleftstep2.gif";
var CutCorners = "../product_images/uploaded_images/cutcornerssquareorrectanglestep2.gif";
var Rounded = "../product_images/uploaded_images/roundedsquareorrectanglestep2.gif";
var TwoCut = "../product_images/uploaded_images/2cutcornersstep2.gif";
var Round = "../product_images/uploaded_images/roundstep2.gif";
var Octagon = "../product_images/uploaded_images/octogonstep2.gif";
var SquareOrRectangle = "../product_images/uploaded_images/squareorrectanglestep2.gif";

// PLACE IMAGES
if ($( ".product h1:contains('Corner Right')" )) {
    $( ".measurement-image" ).append("<img src=\"" + CornerRight + "\" />");
} else if ($( ".product h1:contains('Corner Left')" )) {
    $( ".measurement-image" ).append("<img src=\"" + CornerLeft + "\" />");
} else if ($( ".product h1:contains('Cut Corners')" )) {
    $( ".measurement-image" ).append("<img src=\"" + CutCorners + "\" />");
} else if ($( ".product h1:contains('Rounded')" )) {
    $( ".measurement-image" ).append("<img src=\"" + Rounded + "\" />");
} else if ($( ".product h1:contains('Two Cut')" )) {
    $( ".measurement-image" ).append("<img src=\"" + TwoCut + "\" />");
} else if ($( ".product h1:contains('Octagon')" )) {
    $( ".measurement-image" ).append("<img src=\"" + Octagon + "\" />");
} else if ($( ".product h1:contains('Square or Rectangle')" )) {
    $( ".measurement-image" ).append("<img src=\"" + SquareOrRectangle + "\" />");
} else {
    $( ".measurement-image" ).append("<img src=\"" + Round + "\" />");
}
```

Every time I run it, the first condition (Corner Right) comes back as true, regardless of the actual contents of the H1.

Comment: have you heard about objects and arrays? =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @linstantnoodles said, you are just checking if an array exists, NOT if that array has elements inside it

Also, why not reduce the number of variables and make a single object containing all the checks?  Here's my proposed reworking:

```
var measureSteps = [
    cornerRight: {
        name: "Corner Right",
        src: "../product_images/uploaded_images/onecutcornerrightstep2.gif";
    },
    cornerLeft: {
        name: "Corner Left",
        src: "../product_images/uploaded_images/onecutcornerleftstep2.gif";
    },
    cornerRight: {
        name: "Cut Corners",
        src: "../product_images/uploaded_images/cutcornerssquareorrectanglestep2.gif";
    },
    /* ETC, ETC */
];

//Iterate through each value in the "measureSteps" object, checking if it is contained in h1
var headerText = $('.product h1').text(); //Only do a jQuery matching search once
$.each(measureSteps, function(i, v) {
    if ( headerText.indexOf(v.name) > -1 ) {
        $( ".measurement-image" ).append("<img src='" + v.src + "' />");
        return false; //Stop iterating - we've successfully found the right text!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the **length** of the result (array). All objects are truthy in JavaScript.

For example:

```
if ([]) {
  console.log("Hello");
}
// Prints "Hello"
```